# When parsing a file using antlr 4, How to make a parsetree node cover all input text

Tags: antlr, antlr4

For a simple example, this is lexer file:

```
DIGIT : [0-9];
...
```

And here is parser:

```
integer: DIGIT+;
...
```

when I parse such text `123`, it definitely works. But when I parse `123 456`, it gives me the answer `123`, but the result what I want is an exception that mark the input is invalid.

So how should I use it?

Comment: I know, there is a most cumbersome method，add a line in parser: `integers: integer+`, but I do not want to do that, because what I just want only one Integer.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit `EOF` token produced at the end of the input stream. Use this to match the end like a `$` in most regex languages.

```
integer: DIGIT+ EOF;
```

The above rule will only match if the input looks like one or more digits up to the end of the stream.